# How to set up multiple permission for different folder in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder name folder with name folder1 and another folder with name folder2. I have to set different read and write permission to these two folders.

i have done this in following way.

1) create new svn for my project using svnadmin create myproject -> This generate a folder under /home/svn/myproject(eventhough there is a folder /home/svn/repos)
2) Then i set up conf/passwd as

```
dev1 = dev1
dev2 = dev2

des1 = des1
des2 = des2
```

3) Then my svnserv.conf

```
anon-access = none
auth-access =write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

4) and my authz file have

```
[groups]
developers = dev1,dev2
designers = des1, des2

[myproject:/dev_folder]
@developers = rw
@designers = none

[myproject:/des_folder]
@developers = none
@designers = rw
```

The dev_folder and des_folder are two folder under my project.

I think i have set up all correctly but when i check out or try to commit to svn it says inavlid authz configuration. Can anybody help me on this?

Also one more thing when i install svn there is a folder `repos` under `/home/svn`. But when i create a new svn the svn folder /home/svn folder not under /home/svn/repos. Can anybody tell me what is the purpose of the folder repos?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want two separate repos - that is if you really don't want the designers to even read `dev_folder`.  I think this will be your best bet

```
[groups]
developers = dev1,dev2
designers = des1, des2

[/]
@developers = r
@designers = r

[myproject:/dev_folder]
@developers = rw
@designers = r

[myproject:/des_folder]
@developers = r
@designers = rw
```